# Datatable + jquery UI button

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datatables

I'm using a Datatable (as in Datatables.net) and formatting it myself. In order to make the pagination buttons look nice I'm doing this:

```
$(function(){
    $('#data').dataTable({
        "fnDrawCallback" : function() {
            $('#data_next').button();
            $('#data_previous').button();
        }           
    });
} );
```

The problem is, although the fnDrawCallback event gets fired when the page is changed, the .button() calls seem to be happening before the Datatable is finished with the DOM. It looks like the  inside the  still has the Button classes on it, but the  itself has them removed.

I thought the fnDrawCallback happened *after* the Datatable was finshed drawing, but apparently not.

Suggestions?

Comment: Does that get called every time there's a pagination event?

Comment: I did not have the chance to try yet, but you could try it

Comment: Sorry, it does not trigger when you change pages, but you could probably just apply the JQueryUI button class to them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should read the documentation, your answer is there:

http://datatables.net/styling/custom_classes

One other thing to consider is that DataTable as full Jquery UI integration:

http://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/themes.html

**With this Initialization:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  oTable = $('#example').dataTable({
    "bJQueryUI": true,
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers"
  });
});
```

*You just need to set your preferred theme and make what ever changes you want to the css.*

---

**Going a litle further,** take a look at the dataTable demo for the Jquery UI ThemeRoller support:
http://datatables.net/styling/themes/redmond